# Why doesn't this coffescript code work?

Tags: coffeescript

I am trying to make a function that lists all properties of an object

```
showProps = (obj) ->
 result = ""
 result+= String(i+ ' = ' + obj[i] + '\n') for i in obj when obj.hasOwnProperty(i)
 return result
O = {A:1}
alert showProps O
```

Why does the function return nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `for...in` loops are for looping over arrays.  To iterate over an object, you want `for...of` (which compiles to Javascript's `for...in`).

If you use

```
result+= String(i+ ' = ' + obj[i] + '\n') for i of obj when obj.hasOwnProperty(i)
```

then you will get the result you're looking for.

As @muistooshort pointed out, you can get the `hasOwnProperty` part for free in CoffeeScript with `own`, which makes the code a bit simpler:

```
result+= String(i+ ' = ' + obj[i] + '\n') for own i of obj
```

Comment: Why not `for own i of obj` instead of `when obj.hasOwnProperty(i)`?

Comment: I made the smallest change that showed what was wrong and how to fix it.  That is probably worth mentioning, though.

Answer (score 1):

You want an `for [own] of`-[loop](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to iterate over properties:

```
showProps = (obj) ->
 result = ""
 result+= String(i+ ' = ' + v + '\n') for own i, v of obj
 return result
O = {A:1}
alert showProps O
```

Btw, you don't need the explicit `String` call since you're concatenating strings anyway, and your whole function could be defined more easily as an array comprehension:

```
showProps = (obj) ->
  (i+' = '+v  for own i, v of obj).join('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you used wrong operator. *in* is meant to be used for iterating through collections, like an *array* for example. You would like to use *of* operator.

Besides I changed your example a bit to make it more CoffeeScript way:

```
showProps = (obj) ->
  result = ""
  result += "#{i} = #{v} \n" for i, v of obj when obj.hasOwnProperty(i)
  result
anObject = A:1
alert showProps anObject
```